# UV protection on window now purply in colour and scratched. How to remove?

Tags: repair, windows, glass

On one window the glass is etched and off colour.   No idea what damaged it.  Can it be removed with any kind of product?  it is factory installed.  Not a DIY covering.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to know what you're talking about without more info, and perhaps a picture. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hello again. It looks like you now have [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/103530) different [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/103551); you should use the SE contact form to [ask that they be merged](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, it would still be helpful to add a picture if you could.